# search problem: ABC = abc in C# how to solve this?

Tags: winforms

i have this code for fast search

```
Tmp = "";
            MAK = "";
            DES = "";
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
            Cmd.CommandText = "Ham";
            Cmd.IndexName = "B";
            Cmd.SetRange(DbRangeOptions.Match , new object[] { txtMa.Text }, null);
            SqlCeDataReader read = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (read.Read())
            {
                Tmp     = read[2].ToString(); 
                MAK     = read[0].ToString(); 
                DES     = read[1].ToString();
            }
            read.Dispose();
            if (Tmp == "")
            {

                return false;
            }
            else
            {

                txtDes.Text = DES;
                return true;
            }
```

it works excellent - but the problem is

when i search `ABC` and when i search `abc` i get the same resault

how to separate between them ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case-sensitivity of SQL searches would be a setting of your database.

In particular for SQL Compact Edition you need to make sure you are using a 3.5 SP1+ database with collation enabled at creation time, or otherwise apply these changes:

> If you are referring to 3.5 RTM
>   created file as old file, then you
>   have an option: Using Server Explorer
>   of Visual Studio or Object Explorer of
>   SSMS:
>   1. Connect to the file
>   2. Select the file and right-click on it. Select Database Properties.
>   3. In Shrink and Repair pane of Database Properties dialog, you can
>   change the Case Sensitive feature to
>   true with the help of Advanced
>   Properties dialog activated by
>   Advanced button. P.S. You will have to
>   perform either Compact or Repair
>   operation.
>
> For SQL CE files of 3.1 or previous
>   version, you have to follow the same
>   procedure but have to first upgrade
>   that file to 3.5 SP1.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/649f10a8-6880-46c4-82db-fb52b29614b9

I would recommend reading that source as it yields important information such as how case-sensitivity breaks backwards compatibility.